# how to stabilize a wobbly dining table

Tags: repair, furniture

I have a antique dining table with pedestal type legs on each end. The table has no support piece across the length because it also has leaves and a drop leaf on each end. how can I stabilize this table? it rocks back and forth while you eat if anyone leans on it.

Comment: can you include a pic of the legs?

Comment: You need to look at the table and tell us what is rocking.  Are all four feet staying solidly on the floor, but the table itself is changing shape?  Or is it solid on two feet and the other two are bumping up and down on the floor?

Comment: squirt gorrilla glue in between any two parts with a visible gap. It expands and hardens as it cures and will leave wobbly connections/sockets/joints tight and sturdy.

Answer (score 1):

Check the four corners of the table, underneath it. There should be a bolt or two coming from each leg thru the frame with a washer and nut on it. Get an adjustable wrench and tighten all the nuts. Good luck.